# Why is there no "byte" kind in the reflect package?

Tags: reflection, go, types

I see all sorts of [Kind](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind) enums in Go's `reflect` package. But no `byte`.

Why is that? There is a definite distinction made between the other numeric types. Why not `byte`? Are we supposed to assume `uint8` instead?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, [`byte` is an alias for `uint8`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types): "all numeric types are distinct *except* `byte`, which is an alias for `uint8`, and `rune`, which is an alias for `int32`" (italics mine). You can even write code like `var x []uint8 = []byte("hi!")` [and it compiles](https://play.golang.org/p/xLr7-uDIEe).

Since there's no difference except in how the source is written, the `reflect` package can't do much special with `byte`s when manipulating the (identical) structures in RAM at runtime.

Thinking more about `Kind`s specifically, they refer to *data storage* rather than *type names*. So, for example, if you declare `type A uint8`, variables of types `A` and `uint8` [will have distinct `reflect.Type`s but the same `Kind`](https://play.golang.org/p/cWqmLJvdel):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A uint8

func main() {
    x, y := A(1), uint8(1)
    valX, valY := reflect.ValueOf(x), reflect.ValueOf(y)
    fmt.Println("Types: x is", valX.Type(), "y is", valY.Type())
    fmt.Println("Types match:", valX.Type() == valY.Type())
    fmt.Println("Kinds: x is", valX.Kind(), "y is", valY.Kind())
    fmt.Println("Kinds match:", valX.Kind() == valY.Kind())
}
```

has output

```
Types: x is main.A y is uint8
Types match: false
Kinds: x is uint8 y is uint8
Kinds match: true
```

So though it's a little silly to think about hypothetical languages, even if Go `byte` were a distinct type rather than an alias, they'd have the same `reflect.Kind`.

Comment: Cool, I didn't realize it was defined as an alias by the language spec. (And why is a rune an `int32` instead of a `uint32`, huh?)

Comment: Hard to say! Bytes kinda have to be unsigned because all values are valid and it's convention that they're 0-255. For Unicode code point they had a choice since there aren't more than 2^31 code points. I think they weakly prefer signed ints some places (like array indices) because unsigned wraparound (`0-1==0xffffffff`) can be unintuitive. On the other hand, bit-shift amounts are defined to be uints! (Maybe that's because attempting to do a negative shift can act weirdly in architecture-dependent ways, rather than just being invalid by convention.)